# How to show the directions (arrows in the graph) for a ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

```
f[t_] := 2*t - 3;
f1[t_] := 6*t - 7;
ParametricPlot[{f[t], f1[t]}, {t, -3, 3}]
```

The above code shows the graph... but it can't show me the directions. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 3):

One way to post-process your plot (caveat: will probably not work for any combination):

```
f[t_] := 2*t - 3; f1[t_] := 6*t - 7; 
ParametricPlot[{f[t], f1[t]}, {t, -3, 3}] /.  Line[content___] :> {Arrowheads[ConstantArray[0.05, 5]], Arrow[content]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thnx....to you.

Answer (score 2):

This question may get marked as a duplicate, there are many question about adding arrows to plots, but none of them has an answer of how to programmatically add an arrow for a parametric plot.  For that answer, I looked to [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/315937?p_p_auth=A9zGKN7n) post on Wolfram Community,

```
arrowParametricPlot[f_List, p_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Block[{δ = (p[[3]] - p[[2]])/100.}, 
   ParametricPlot[f, p, 
    Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ParametricPlot]]], 
    Epilog -> {Arrowheads[.1, 0], 
      Arrow[{f /. p[[1]] -> p[[3]] - δ, 
        f /. p[[1]] -> p[[3]]}]}, PlotRange -> All]] /; 
  Length[f] == 2 && 
   Length[p] == 3 && ! FreeQ[f[[1]], p[[1]]] && ! 
    FreeQ[f[[2]], p[[1]]]
```

See that it will show the direction of the parametric curve,

```
{arrowParametricPlot[{f[t], f1[t]}, {t, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> 100],
 arrowParametricPlot[{f[t], f1[t]}, {t, 3, -3}, ImageSize -> 100]}
```

[image]